# sort by keep keys and keep value order?

Tags: php

I have an

```
$a = array(9=>"a",8=>"c",5=>"d");
```

I want to sort the only keys of array `$a` and keep order of values.

so it will be  `array(5=>"a",8=>"c",9=>"d");`

How Could I DO in php array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorting the keys, but keep the values in order is not possible by just ordering, because it would result in a new array. This is also the solution: Create a new array

```
$keys = array_keys($a);
sort($keys);
$result = array_combine($keys, array_values($a));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ksort() to do this http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php